# React Router v4: <Route> component unable to match urls with question marks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using a React.js app as a widget inside a Wordpress admin area. The way some users configure wordpress urls can use query parameters to set the page view, for example:

```
domain.com/wpFolder/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=settingspage
```

I want to be able to set my Links and Routes to conform to this structure so that page reloads don't break. I am unable to do this, adding slashes/subfolders is fine but the moment I add `?` the `<Route />` no longer matches. Example:

```
      <StyledMaterialLink // This is a <Link /> wrapped by Styled Components
        component={RouterLink}
        to={`/wptest2/wp-admin/options-general.php?`}> 
        <Tab
          label="See Current Coupons"
          value={seeCurrentCoupons}
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(location.href, `=====location.href=====`); 
            setAdminView(seeCurrentCoupons)
          }}
        />
    </StyledMaterialLink>

    <Route
      path={`/wptest2/wp-admin/options-general.php?`}
      render={props => {

        return (
          <CurrentCouponChannel.Provider
            value={state.currentCouponsAndTargets}>
            <ViewCoupons />
          </CurrentCouponChannel.Provider>
        )
      }}
    />
```

Eventually I would like the `<Route path />` above to end with &section=view-coupons as well.

Is it possible to hardcode query string params this way to work after reloading with my framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search parameters are not part of the path. You can access those values through props.location

```
    <Route
      path={`/wptest2/wp-admin/options-general.php`}
      render={props => {
        // do something with props.location.search
```

The library https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string is helpful here.

Comment: Thank you. As every route should match that path without query strings I guess it should become a parent route then? And all routes, being defined by hardcoded query string params, should become sub-routes?

Comment: You can do it that way. You can also create your own component that wraps Route in order to handle the query strings in the way you want them instead of creating subroutes